# How to make a looping boat ride?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, so now that boat elevators were fixed, how can you set a boat to infinitely repeat a loop?

I.E. I have a boat follow a current I made, and it ends up several levels lower then the start.  How can I raise the boat back up?

Comment: While I'm unsure of the actual mechanics, it may be possible with pistons, but it probably breaks the boat if aren't in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This information will likely change as water physics change fairly often.*

[EthosLab](http://www.youtube.com/user/EthosLab) discovered that the new interaction between boats and water has very strange quirks. For example, he found that while boats won't rise in water usually, they *will* rise **if the water consists completely of "water source blocks"** (no stream blocks). It's more difficult (and more time consuming) than the old method because you need to place each individual water block in your elevator, but it works. Here is a video of him constructing it and then testing it.

Also, if you want to make a boat ride that stays on one level, you can build an EATS Road (which is conveniently featured in the video above as well). It's essentially a transportation system that keeps a boat at its maximum speed all the time, making it as efficient as travel by minecart. The way it's constructed allows for the "track" to stay on one level all the time, which is perfect for a boat ride as well (you can of course add rises and drops if wanted).

Comment: Excellent!  I now have a working EATS road with a working water elevator!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. :)